# Casting a String as an int, incrementing the int, and seeing the change in an exported CSV file

Tags: string, powershell, csv, int

In a CSV file which I am importing into PowerShell, I have headers and rows of data. Some of the data are integers within Strings; here is an example of what the CSV file looks like:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
"8", "3", "17"
```

While looping through the file, I am storing certain data as variables and then casting those variables as integers; here is an example:

```
foreach ($x in $file) {
    $firstNumber = $x.Header1
    [int]$firstNumber = $firstNumber
}
```

I know I am casting correctly because if I run `$firstNumber.GetType().FullName`, the output reads `System.Int32`.

Here is where I run into my problem. Using an `if` statement, I am trying to increment the integer and then export it into a new CSV file. Here is an example:

```
if ($firstNumber -ge 5) {
    $firstNumber = 1 + $firstNumber
}
$x.Header1 = $firstNumber
$file | Export-Csv 'C:\path\export.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

I know that the values are changing correctly within Powershell because if I run `echo $firstNumber` anywhere after the line `$firstNumber = 1  + $firstNumber`, the output reads `9`; thus the change just isn't writing to the exported file. Other changes I am making to the imported data and then exporting to the new CSV file are showing, though those are just strings in which their data types aren't being cast as different ones.

---

I have created a new CSV file to test that has much less substance, and I have also created a new PowerShell script that is only working with the little data I have in the new CSV file.

New CSV file being imported:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4
"8", "3", "17", "Text"
```

New PowerShell script:

```
# import file
$file = Import-Csv 'C:\Import.csv'
foreach ($x in $file) {
    $firstNumber = $x.Header1
    [int]$firstNumber = $firstNumber
}
if ($firstNumber -ge 5) {
    $firstNumber = 1 + $firstNumber
}
$x.Header1 = $firstNumber
$x.Header4 = "DifferentText"
$file | Export-Csv 'C:\Export.csv'
```

Output written to new CSV file:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4"
"9","3","17","DifferentText"
```

Comment: You set $x.Header1, but then export $file. Never do you set the actual item in $file.

Comment: @JacobColvin Is there any reason this method works with other data? For example, in my CSV file, I have `Header4`, and in the row beneath it in the same column the data is equal to `"Text"`. After importing the CSV file, I change that data in the following manner: `$x.Header4 = "DifferentText"`. Then I use the same export statement as stated above, and the new exported CSV file is showing the changes I made, even though I did it the same way you said that is not changing the actual item in `$file`. Why does this method work sometimes and not other times?

Comment: Could you post your actual code?

Comment: @JacobColvin What I am trying to get done is now working (see edit to original question) so there must be something within the code of my original script which is stopping this from happening.

Comment: The original code "worked" (i.e. the right things were being done) but you had a number of things set out of scope. The answer below has them set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I put your three parts correctly together I get your expected output.

```
$file = import-csv file.csv

foreach ($x in $file) {
    $firstNumber = $x.Header1
    [int]$firstNumber = $firstNumber
    if ($firstNumber -ge 5) {
        $firstNumber = 1 + $firstNumber
        # $firstnumber += 1    # two alternative ways to increment
        # $firstnumber++
    }
    $x.Header1 = $firstNumber
}
$file | Export-Csv '.\export.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
> gc .\export.csv
"Header1","Header2","Header3"
"9","3","17"
```